# Challenge: How to store a large number of sets to quickly calculate the sum of the values taken by the elements in each set?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, dynamic-programming, graph-theory

I would like to ask for your opinion. Which data structure and algorithm should I use to efficiently solve the following problem?

**Question:**

> **Given** *M*(10≤*M*≤1000) elements and *N* sets built from these elements. There are no duplicate elements in each set. The number of sets may be more than tens of thousands, which has a certain relationship with the number of elements.
>
> **Input** the values *X* (type of double, 0≤*X*≤1) of the *M* elements
>
> **Find** the set with the largest sum of element values among the *N* sets.

**For example:**

> **Precondition:** Given 5 elements and 5 sets
>
> ```
> X = (A,B,C,D,E), S = [(A,B),(C,D),(B,C,E),(B,D,E),(A,C,D,E)]
> ```

> **Input:** The value of **X** is
>
> ```
> X = (0.2, 0.8, 0.6, 0.3, 0.5)
> ```

> **Result:** The set with the largest sum of element values is
>
> ```
> sum(B,C,E) = 0.8 + 0.6 + 0.5 = 1.9
> ```

In some sets, there are common subsequences that can be combined and stored to reduce the space complexity and reduce the time complexity of the summation algorithm. What data structure do you recommend to store these sets? What is the time complexity of the summation algorithm?

Comment: I guess that "sets consisting of M elements" is a misleading explanation. You probably mean built from these elements.

Comment: Presumably, preprocessing the sets is allowed. Please confirm.

Comment: How large is N ? How large are the sets ?

Comment: I have the feeling that an optimal solution is intractable.

Comment: What is the range of the input values?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thanks for your correction, I have edited the question. We can preprocess these known N sets and save them through a data structure. The number of sets may be more than tens of thousands, which has a certain relationship with the number of elements. The number of elements is usually less than or equal to one thousand.

Comment: Should this data structure help to answer the question for the **same** sets, but with multiple, **different** value assignments (different X)? Or is this just a one shot query, with one input and corresponding output? In the latter case, I doubt that a special data structure will help, as the time to build it will be the time needed to find the maximum. A data structure might help when you have multiple queries on it (multiple X).

Comment: @user3386109 The range of the input values is usually greater than or equal to 0 and less than or equal to 1.

Comment: @trincot Yes, the sets is always the same but there will be different X as input.

Comment: The number of possible subsets being exponential, I believe that you can only address this problem with heuristic methods. The problem structure seems to match well with genetic algorithms.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Use an array to store these sets, and then traverse and sum the elements contained in each sets. This problem can be solved in O(MN). Because there are many collections containing some common subsequences, I wonder if there is a data structure that can link these sets to reduce storage space and speed up the calculations.  
With the genetic algorithm, the time complexity may be even greater, and the optimality cannot be guaranteed.

Comment: Ok, you are not obliged to believe what I said.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Anyway, thanks for your suggestion. The number of subsets will be large, but not exponential. Because there are other conditions restricting the formation of sets.

Comment: The number of subsets of a set is exponential.

Comment: What you're looking for is dictionary-based compression. The only such algorithm that I've actually used is [LZW compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lempel–Ziv–Welch) which computes the dictionary on the fly. LZW is simple and fast, but won't give the best compression ratio. So I'd start by googling "dictionary based compression techniques".

Comment: @user3386109 Your idea inspired me, I can search for some longest common subsequences and use dictionary-based compression to compress these common subsequences. However, the number of sets is huge, so the method of searching for the longest subsequence still needs to be thought about carefully.

Comment: You could express S as matrix of 0s and 1s, then you get the sum vector by matrix multiplication. A good library might be able to do this multiplication and get max value in vector fast enough.

Comment: Obviously the sum calculation can be highly parallelized. Which is easier than somehow finding best candidates and trying to reduce the number of additions/comparisons.

Comment: Yup, finding a reasonably good dictionary is the challenge. Given that your "alphabet" has 1000 characters, and the number of "words" is in the tens of thousands, and each of the "words" has up to 1000 characters, finding the dictionary is going to be computationally expensive no matter how you do it.

Comment: I can help with finding the letters that two words have in common. Start by noting that it takes 2 bytes of storage to store one letter, since there can be up to 1000 different letters. So a word with 1000 letters takes 2000 bytes of storage. But you know that each letter can only appear once, and the order doesn't matter. So you can encode a word as 128 bytes (or sixteen 64-bit values). Each bit is a 1 if the corresponding letter is in the word, 0 otherwise. Then you can find all of the common letters just by ANDing the two bit patterns together.

Comment: @user3386109 Thanks for your advice. I'll have a try.

Answer (score -3):

i think a good start would be to build a TREE OF ALL THE INPUT SETS:

"empty" root, then 1 child for every first element in each set, then according to the input sets, like the example: child A will have children B and C, child B will have C and D and so on...

to find the best sum, run DFS on the tree while substituting each element with it's value from X and remember route of the leaf with the highest sum.

using a tree as your data structure, gives you a "fake-memoization" because you can compute and keep the sum for each node and not recalculating it.

Comment: Your description is unclear, and I don't see where subsums are reused.

Comment: yes it is. read again:
Find the set with the largest sum of element values among the N sets
just remember the route you took on the tree and return it.

Comment: I deleted that wrong comment.

Comment: subsums are used during the DFS, when you compute the sum for each node, and pass it to each child as you compute their sum. like i said, "fake-memoization".

Comment: You did not really explain how the tree is built, which is the crux of the question. And if you only account for the initial sets, you will miss many opportunities to build useful subsums.

Comment: I don't think that "put them in a tree and DFS" is a significant contribution, sorry.

Comment: i did explain exactly how to build the tree. empty root, then go over the all the input sets and create a child for the first element, the for each child, create a child of the second element in each set and so on. its not complicated.

Comment: in dynamic programing, every solution is recursion+memoization or tree+dfs (which are almost the same thing). do you have a better solution? lets see it.

Comment: Presumably you are addressing me. Check my comments to the OP.

Comment: @TomElias I understand your idea of using a tree and dynamic programming, but I don't know how to construct the tree so that the storage space will be as small as possible. This is probably the most challenging part of the problem.

Comment: the storage will be minimal becuase the sets { A, B, C} and {A, B, D} both share the route () -> A -> B and B will have 2 children C and D.

Comment: @TomElias Then I should find some sets containing the longest common subsequence, and then save these sets in the tree with the common subsequence as the parent node. Does my description fit your idea?